# Chrome Dev Tool Timeline says I have orphaned DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a Single Page App in Backbone.js that is meant to scale to 10K photos. I'm trying to test the limits of Chrome and see if I'll hit this webkit bug:

[Unbounded memory growth when adding and removing images](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31253)

I'm loading JPGs into the DOM tree using and instanceof Backbone.View into the DOM tree and calling the following to remove:

```
// myThmbnailView instanceof Backbone.View
myThumbnailView.undelegateEvents();
myThumbnailView.remove();
```

The ThumbnailView has no event handlers declared, everything is delegated to the parent, GalleryView.

According to the Timeline on ChromeDevTools, I have 1000s of DOM nodes on my Page, (each ThumbnailView contains 20 DOM elements), but they are not released when I iterate through my thumbnails and remove. Here is a snapshot

[image: Timeline Snapshot]

A final call of `$("body").children().remove()` to remove all DOM elements from the page still leaves me with 18K DOM nodes according to the Timeline. However, GC seems to free up significant memory.

Do I have orphaned nodes or is this a Timeline bug? Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

Comment: how many elements are in the $.cache object? does clearing it make any difference?

Comment: I did another run and found 7 keys for the run above, and 2 keys after I called "$("body").children().remove()"  What is $.cache, I didn't see any docs on it?

Comment: I've enhanced my test script and it seems like I can run 50+ cycles of loading/removing 3500 JPGs without crashing the browser. But the DevTools Tmmeline never goes below 70K DOM nodes after removing the JPGs - and sometimes crashes.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm experiencing a similar thing with my app. It gets to around 80-100K nodes. I started doing some simple testing but I'm unlcear if this is a bug or actual orphaned nodes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240709/javascript-freeing-the-dom?noredirect=1#comment31997059_21240709

Comment: No. But I did run it for hours and while ChromeDevTools sometimes crashed, the browser session rarely did. So I'm hoping it's just a Timeline bug