# Javascript Freeing the DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-devtools

I've written a fairly large web app. It works good for awhile and then slowly starts running sluggish as DOM nodes start creeping around 80,000 - 100,000.

So I've been screweing around with some small data sets in the Chrome Dev Tools console (DCTC).

Can someone tell me why the following works sometimes and then sometimes it does not.

```
var test = $('<div></div>');
test.remove();
test = null; //Doesn't seem to make a difference when it doesn't work
```

If I watch the DOM node count under Timeline in CDT, the sometimes the node count will be correct, other times it seems to refuse to give up the DOM node I'm trying to remove. This is even after pushing the GC button.

The following seems to be consistent in removing the DOM nodes and freeing memory.

```
//Seems to remove nodes just fine
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
    var test = $('<div></div>');
    $("body").append(test);
}
$("body").empty();
```

In regards to the first example, I thought that perhaps it didn't work sometimes because of the NODELETE flag because it's a variable definition, so I tried putting my assignment on an object but that did not help. It actually seems to be more consistent that jQuery's remove would not remove the dom node.

```
//Does not remove the node.
var test = {};
test.node = $('<div></div>');
test.node.remove();
test.node = null;
```

Why the inconsistency?

Observation:

if I do `test = document.createElement('div');` it will consistently create a detached node.  `var test = ....` seems to be consistent in allowing me to clear the node until it messes up and then all bets are off.

In response to everyone saying there is no DOM node, please read this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks  The DOM nodes I'm trying to delete show up here in the detached dom nodes, but "how do I get rid of them" is the looming question still.

Comment: `$('<div></div>')` creates a new element, removing it on the next line makes no sense, as it's not in the DOM ?

Comment: You are creating a div and not appeding it anywhere , so it's not in DOM. remove won't do annything

Comment: @adeneo Which is fine, but setting the variable to null doesn't remove the DOM node either. So any reference to it is lost and GC does not collect it. THIS makes no sense.

Comment: Until you have actually added it to the DOM there's nothing to remove, it's just a variable holding an element, and when setting the variable to null, what DOM node did you expect to be removed ?

Comment: So are you telling me that Chrome Dev tools is incorrect in it's DOM count reporting? If you create an element using `$('<div></div>');` or by using `document.createElement('<div>');` the DOM count goes up, but never goes back down. Regardless of whether it's inserted into the page, Chrome Dev tools seems to think they are hanging around somewhere. Is this incorrect? I just want my DOM node count to go down :)

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing, here is what I came up with:

The console does correctly show the DOM node counts. It also however seems to handle variable declaration and removing DOM nodes incorrectly. If I run my examples from script, they work just fine, not from the console though.

If I do:

```
        <script>
            var test = document.createElement('div');
            test = null;
            var test = {};
            test.node = document.createElement('div');
            delete test.node;


            var test = $('<div><div></div><div></div></div>');
            test.on("click", function(){
                alert('yes');
            });
            test.remove();
            test = null;
            //test = null;

            var test2 = {};
            test2.node = $('<div></div>');
            test2.node.remove();
            delete test2.node;
        </script>
```

From inside my page, it correctly frees up the memory and orphaned DOM nodes. If I do not set the variable to NULL or delete it from an object, the detached DOM node will remain there and there is no way to remove it as you don't have a reference to it anymore.

I think this is a good word of caution to those using jQuery and relying on the remove() function solely.

Comment: You need to take care when debugging/analyzing memory usage (object allocations) with gc. When you set an object to `null` or call `delete` on the property, it is not removed from memory immediately. It could stay in memory for hours, if the engine has enough memory remaining, you will often see a growing of memory until a certain threshold and then a rapid decrease  to a certain threshold when the gc is triggered, to avoid application blocking, there is no full release  of all unused objects performed.

Comment: True, but there is a GC button in Chrome Dev Tools that is suppose to trigger the GC right away.